# Deadlock only when running Cython compiled .py but not when running from interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, deadlock, concurrent.futures, cythonize

The following example code runs as expected when running from interpreter. However, when i cythonize the example and then import the compiled module i'm faced with a deadlock.

Do you know what's the reason for this behaviour? Can i workaround somehow? Would it be possible to implement a timeout, so that the thread is terminated after a certain amount of time, anyway?

```
from concurrent import futures
import time

class StopFlag:
    def __init__(self):
        self._started = 0
    
    @property
    def started(self):
        return self._started
        
    def stop(self):
        self._started = 0
        
    def start(self):
        self._started = 1
        
    
def my_loop(stop_flag):
        total_records = 0

        print ("Started loop")
        # wait until measurement is running actively
        while not stop_flag.started:
            pass
        
        print ("Started measurement")
        # wait until measurement is over            
        while stop_flag.started:
            pass
        
        print ("Measurement over")


stop_flag = StopFlag()

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as t:
    t.submit(my_loop, stop_flag)

    time.sleep(1)
    stop_flag.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    stop_flag.stop()
```

Interpreted:

```
$ py -3.6 treading.py
Started loop
Started measurement
Measurement over
```

Cythonized:

```
$ cythonize -ai3 treading.py
Compiling C:\mydir\Trials\treading.py because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing C:\mydir\Trials\treading.py
running build_ext
building 'treading' extension
creating C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release
creating C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir
creating C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir\Trials
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /TcC:\mydir\Trials\treading.c /FoC:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir\Trials\treading.obj
treading.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\libs" "/LIBPATH:c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_treading C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir\Trials\treading.obj /OUT:C:\mydir\Trials\treading.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir\Trials\treading.cp36-win_amd64.lib
   Bibliothek "C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir\Trials\treading.cp36-win_amd64.lib" und Objekt "C:\mydir\Trials\tmpcu1r5lge\Release\mydir\Trials\treading.cp36-win_amd64.exp" werden erstellt.
Code wird generiert.
Codegenerierung ist abgeschlossen.

$ py -3.6 -c "import treading;"
Started loop
<< deadlock >>
```

Here is the compiled code of the `future.submit` call:

```
+38: with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as t:
+39:     t.submit(my_loop, stop_flag)
          __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_n_s_t); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 39, __pyx_L6_error)
          __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
          __pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_n_s_submit); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 39, __pyx_L6_error)
          __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
          __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
          __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_n_s_my_loop); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 39, __pyx_L6_error)
          __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
          __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_n_s_stop_flag); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 39, __pyx_L6_error)
          __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
          __pyx_t_8 = PyTuple_New(2); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_8)) __PYX_ERR(0, 39, __pyx_L6_error)
          __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_8);
          __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_t_2);
          PyTuple_SET_ITEM(__pyx_t_8, 0, __pyx_t_2);
          __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_t_1);
          PyTuple_SET_ITEM(__pyx_t_8, 1, __pyx_t_1);
          __pyx_t_2 = 0;
          __pyx_t_1 = 0;
          __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyObject_Call(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_8, NULL); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 39, __pyx_L6_error)
          __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
          __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
          __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_8); __pyx_t_8 = 0;
          __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I know nothing about cython, I tried it for first time today. This "answer" does not really answer the question.

I tested this on Linux, and problem is present too. Code behaves as if cooperative multitasking would be used. If I add to `StopFlag.started` a `time.sleep(0)`, or only open a file (without reading it), then it works. Might be useful as workaround.

Edit 2:
Seems to be GIL related. The change below helps (on my system at least).

```
class StopFlag:
     @property
     def started(self):
+        with nogil:
+            pass
         return self._started
```

So I guess, thread running my_loop is holding GIL all the time (it was using 100% CPU on my system), and the main thread did not get GIL to be able to really change stop_flag value.

To check this, a second change:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as t:
    t.submit(my_loop, stop_flag)

    time.sleep(1)
    print("before stop_flag.start")
    stop_flag.start()
    print("after stop_flag.start")
    time.sleep(1)
    stop_flag.stop()
```

I still get on terminal only:

```
python -c "import treading;"
Started loop
```

After `t.submit`, the main thread did execute any other line of code, and `before stop_flag.start` was not printed.

Comment: I actually can't follow your explanation as the code seems to hang on the `t.submit`, not at one of the while loops. However, thank you for providing an attempt to explain the behavior.

Comment: 100% cpu is very bad! I now see that the interpreter needs some time for each run of the while loop and leaves some cpu time to other threads. On the other hand, the compiled code is so fast, that it runs the loop tightly. It was just a bad idea of mine how i implemented the while loop. I should have used a time.sleep(smalltime) in the while body. I tested this now again and it proved to be the source of the hazzle. So be careful with tight loops when using Cython. I say again: It's just a bad idea!